# Как проверить что строка состоит только из букв, цифр и пробелов python?

Tags: python

Ребят подскажите как проверить что имя состоит только из букв, цифр и пробелов?

```
        while True:
            name_product = input('Введите имя продукта(разрешается использовать только буквы и цифры)> ')
            if name_product.isspace() or name_product.isalnum():
                break
            else:
                print('Введите корректное имя продукта')
```

например имя может быть такое : куриное филе1

Comment: Регуляркой проверь, что строка НЕ содержит символа, НЕ входящего в указанный список.

Comment: А подробнее можно?

Comment: Не-а... не пользую я питон, а искать, как строки в нём проверяются регулярками, мне лень. А алгоритмически - не понимаю, куда уж подробнее...

Comment: Делаем список, что можно юзать и для каждой буквы поверяем входит ли она в список, иначе просим ввести корректное имя

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы должны проверить, что **все символы** введённого названия соответствуют вашим критериям (пробел, буква или цифра), соответственно, код проверки можно преобразовать так:

```
    if all(x.isspace() or x.isalnum() for x in name_product):
        break
```

Т.е. перебираем все символы названия через `for`, каждый символ проверяем вашим условием `isspace or isalnum`, и проверяем, что все эти условия выполнились одновременно с помощью функции `all`.